# Does Castro hold the record for re-election speech length, among heads of government/state?

Tags: comparative-politics, rhetoric, head-of-state

[According](https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-cuba-castro-facts-factbox-idUKKBN13L04C) to Reuters:

> Castro holds the record for the longest speech ever delivered to the United Nations: 4 hours and 29 minutes, on Sept. 26, 1960, according to the U.N. website. One of his longest speeches on record lasted 7 hours and 30 minutes on Feb. 24, 1998, after the national assembly re-elected him to a five-year term as president.

(The first part of the claim needs to be amended with the [fact](https://ask.un.org/faq/37127) that it's the longest UN*GA* speech. At the UNSC there was a considerably longer intervention by an Indian representative, [probably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V._K._Krishna_Menon#Speech_on_Kashmir) intended to delay/filibuster a decision, while "facts on the ground" were being established in Kashmir.)

Anyhow, my question is about the 2nd part of that paragraph. Is the 7.5-hours reelection speech a record in that category, if we restrict ourselves to heads of state/government? (You can include fist-time acceptance/victory speeches, if you think that would yield a different answer.)

Comment: Chavez 9 1/2 hours. https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2012-01-16/chavez-gives-9-hour-speech-ahead-of-campaign#xj4y7vzkg

Comment: @RickSmith: you can make it an answer...

Comment: Bloomberg wants me register. I won't. Feel free to use it as a self-answer. Could also use the [tag:head-of-state] tag.

Comment: @RickSmith No need to register, just skip that registration dialog.

Comment: *Fact check?* [Longest UN speech](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-un-speech): The longest speech ever given to the UN was delivered in 1957 by the Indian politician VK Krishna Menon, who talked for nearly eight hours while defending India's position on Kashmir. Also, https://ask.un.org/faq/37127 which mentions both Menon and Castro.

Comment: @RickSmith: isn't that info included in my Q already?

Comment: In the Reuters article about Castro, it is natural the author would mention *facts* about Castro; but the Guinness World Records article disputes a particular *fact* about Castro. IOW, the Reuters article is missing the "timed" aspect of Castro's speech. My comment simply identifies the discrepancy in the Reuters article. It has no other bearing on your Q, since Menon was not a head of state. I thought that the limitation on the comment would have been clear by referencing only the "Longest UNs speech".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The longest speach seems to be [Nutuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutuk) by Atatürk. The speach was from 15 to 20 October 1927 and took thirty-six hours (on a 6 day span) to be read by Atatürk.

Comment: Is that a *re-election* speech, though? From reading the articles on Ataturk, it doesn't sound like Turkey even *had* elections at that time.

Comment: @F1Krazy So you was only asking about re-election speeches?

Comment: It's not my question, but yes, the question is specifically asking for the longest *re-election* speech.

Comment: @F1Krazy: there [was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1927_Turkish_general_election) actually a general election that year (1927), but Nutuk was a party congress speech. It might be "distinction without a difference" since there was apparently only one party standing in that 1927 election. (I think the president wasn't being directly elected back then though. But I'm also not sure if Ataturk's position within the party was subjected to intra-party elections, ever.)

Comment: One of the ironies of this is that Ataturk apparently gave very few public speeches otherwise, being quite radio-shy https://www.lrb.co.uk/the-paper/v30/n17/perry-anderson/kemalism